# Print foreach inside an html script on php file

Tags: php

I'm having a big problem.
I have this code and I want to print that values in other page.

**FORM**

```
<p>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="reconhecimento_sabado" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Sábado, 4 de Março de 2017<br>" name="reconhecimento[]" onclick="chkChecks('reconhecimento[]')"> Sábado, 4 de Março de 2017
</p>
<p>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="reconhecimento_domingo" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Domingo, 5 de Março de 2017<br>" name="reconhecimento[]" onclick="chkChecks('reconhecimento[]')"> Domingo, 5 de Março de 2017
</p>
<p>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="reconhecimento_quinta" checked> 
    <input type="checkbox" value="Quinta-feira, 9 de Março de 2017<br>" name="reconhecimento[]" onclick="chkChecks('reconhecimento[]')"> Quinta-feira, 9 de Março de 2017
</p>
<p>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="reconhecimento_sexta" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Sexta-feira, 10 de Março de 2017<br>" name="reconhecimento[]" onclick="chkChecks('reconhecimento[]')"> Sexta-feira, 10 de Março de 2017
</p>
```

And here I have the code from the other page, like this I can print my values form the previously page.

```
$reconhecimento = $_POST['reconhecimentos'];

foreach ($reconhecimento as $reconhecimento=>$value) { 
    echo $value; 
}

$html="TESTE de codigo  FIM DO TESTE";
echo $html;
```

But like this I can't, help me please.

```
$reconhecimento = $_POST['reconhecimentos'];

    $html="TESTE de codigo ".foreach ($reconhecimento as $reconhecimento=>$value) { echo $value; }." FIM DO TESTE";

    echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you aren't self-referencing the array you are looping over:

```
foreach ($reconhecimento as $r=>$value) { echo $value; }
```

Also, Don't assign your foreach inside a string. Do this:

```
echo "TESTE de codigo: ";

foreach ($reconhecimento as $r = >$value) { 
    echo $value; 
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: Its the same than 
foreach ($reconhecimento as $reconhecimento=>$value) { echo $value; }
The problem is print the result on html :/